# WAS 8.5.5.9 on java sdk1.6 need to update to java sdk8

Tags: sdk, websphere, ibm-installation-manager

I am trying to update only the java SDK in WebSphere 8.5.5.9 to 8

So far steps performed:-
IBM Instalation Manager was of version 1.5.2 updated it to 1.8.5
I have the javasdk8 (8.0.2.10-WS-IBMWASJAVA-Win) downloaded already.

Started IBM Installation Manager-> Install -> selected IBM WebSphere SDK JAVA Tech Edition -> Next -> Getting message as Operating system is below the recommended minimum level for this product.

It does gives a link to check the details but its not much clear.

Comment: So, what OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the minimum supported levels for Java 8 here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045339

From that doc:

> In **8.5.5.14** and later, or when selecting "IBM WebSphere SDK Java
>   Technology Edition 8.0" at installation time on 8.5.5.11 and later
>   prior operating system releases (such as Windows 2008, HP-UX 11iv2,
>   RedHat Enterprise Linux 5, SLES 11 .0, SLES 10, Solaris 10, and z/OS
>   1.12) **will no longer be supported**.
>
> Operating System minimums:
>
> - AIX
> - AIX 6.1 TL7
> - AIX 7.1 TL3
> - HP-UX IA64
> - HP-UX 11i v3 (11.31)
> - IBM i
> - IBM i V7R1
> - Linux
> - RedHat Enterprise Linux 6
> - RedHat Enterprise Linux 7
> - SLES 11.1 (SP1)
> - SLES 12
> - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
> - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
> - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
> - Windows
> - Windows 7 service pack 1
> - Windows 8 (not Metro)
> - Windows Server 2012
> - Windows Server 2016
> - Solaris
> - Solaris 11
> - z/OS
> - z/OS 1.13
> - z/OS 2.1
> - z/OS 2.2

Hope that helps.